# Five prizes are to be awarded at an event. How many ways can this be done if sixty people are attending, and each person can win at most 2 prizes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This seems like a straightforwards problem, but I feel like I am missing something.

So far, I have:

60C1 x 60C1 x 59C1 x 59C1 x 58C1

However, this only accounts for if the first 2 people both win the maximum amount of prizes. How can I account for each prize going to a different person, or if only 1 person wins 2 prizes?

Comment: Are the prizes different?

Comment: I believe the prizes are identical.

Comment: It's the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{60}=5$, subject to the constraints $0\le x_i\le2$ for $i=1,2,\dots,60$. This kind of question has been asked and answered here numerous times. I'd recommend doing a search.

Comment: The problem would be more interesting if the prizes were distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to divide the outcomes into different categories:

1) Five different people win the prizes (one prize each). $_{60} C_5$ ways for this to happen.

2) There are four winners (three with one prize and one with two prizes). Person with two prizes can be chosen $60$ ways. Other three can be chosen $_{59}C_3$ ways. Total $60 \times {}_{59}C_3$ ways.

3) There are three winners (one with one prize and two with two prizes. Person with one prize can be chosen $60$ ways. Other two can be chosen $_{59}C_2$ ways. Total $60 \times {}_{59}C_2$ ways.

There are no more possibilities.

Overall total is $_{60} C_5 + 60 \times {}_{59}C_3 + 60 \times {}_{59}C_2$ ways.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!